# Error 'int' object is not subscriptable, How do i convert it to list?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I'm a python newbie and still learning,
I have this code:

```
# columns are [0]title [1]year [2]rating [3]length(min) [4]genre [5]budget($mil) [6]box_office_gross($mil)
oscar_data = [
    ["The Shape of Water", 2017, 6.914, 123, ['sci-fi', 'drama'], 19.4, 195.243464],
    ["Moonlight", 2016, 6.151, 110, ['drama'], 1.5, 65.046687],
    ["Spotlight", 2015, 7.489, 129, ['drama', 'crime', 'history'], 20.0, 88.346473],
    ["Birdman", 2014, 7.604, 119, ['drama', 'comedy'], 18.0, 103.215094]
]


def filter_by_genre(data, genre):
    result = []
    for row in data:
        genres = row[4]
        if genre in genres:
            result.append(row)
    return result


all_genres = [
    'sci-fi', 'drama', 'crime', 'history', 'comedy', 'biography',
    'thriller', 'war', 'melodrama', 'action', 'adventure', 'western',
    'mystery', 'horror'
]

genres_counts = []
for genre in all_genres:
    count = len(filter_by_genre(oscar_data, genre))
    genres_counts.append(genre)
    genres_counts.append(count)



print('Genre        | Number')
print('------------------------')
for row in genres_counts:
    genre = row[0]
    count = row[1]
    print('{: <11} | {: >10}'.format(genre, count))
```

I've made the list shorter for the sake of the post, It supposed to count each genre in `oscar_data` and print it with the genre and the count.

I thought I've done it correctly, but I can't print it because it returns the error

```
  File "temp.py", line 63, in <module>
    genre = row[0]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I supposed to do to make that int a list?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the int to be turned into a range? For example, 5 would be turned into the list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is introduced here:

```
genres_counts.append(genre)
genres_counts.append(count)
```

You append the genre and the count as separate values, not as a collection. Replace those two lines with:

```
genres_counts.append((genre, count))
```

Better yet, use list comprehension:

```
genres_counts = [(genre, len(filter_by_genre(oscar_data, genre))  
                 for genre in all_genres]
```

Comment: Thank you, It now works! Will accept the answer ASAP. Why do I need a double `(())`?

Comment: The inner parentheses define a 2-element tuple. Also, look at the edits.